# svg.js square a rectangle

Tags: firefox, svg.js

I made a [square](http://jsfiddle.net/heyzeuss/kSJYG) in jsfiddle using svg.js, but it turned out to be a rectangle in Firefox. I works fine in Chrome. What gives?

```
var rectangle = draw.rect(100,100)
```

Comment: Setting the size on the SVG fixes the problem. That is ```SVG('drawing').size(500, 500)```. I'm not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: That fixes it. The svg frame is cropping off the bottom of the square, because the square does not fit inside.

Answer (score 0):

svg.js automatically sets the height and width to 100% (this is not true for version >=3). When you create the svg in an element which does not have a height specified, it defaults to the browser defaults which are different from browser to browser. When I try something out with svg.js I make sure, that the following styles are applied:

```
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```